# Updating JTable on row insertion

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I am inserting and deleting rows using an AbstractTabelModel. So far I can remove rows from the table by repainting the table, however, I cannot get the JTables to update for insertion.

Things I've tried:

```
.repaint() (JTable and containers)
fireTableRowsInserted(0, getRowCount() - 1)
fireTableDataChanged()
```

However, it only seems to update when I move the srollbar of the JTable, if it has one or if I have deleted first - but it leaves a white background behind.

How do I get rows to update properly on insertion and deletion?

Comment: It is the responsibility of the model to trigger events, to which the view (the `JTable`) will take appropriate actions.  Without further evidence, it would appear that the model you are updating is not attached to the table that is on the screen. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: `I am inserting and deleting rows using an AbstractTabelModel` - just use the `DefaultTableModel` since it already supports this functionality. Or, you if you really need to create a custom TableModel then look at the source code of the `DefaultTableModel` to see how it handles insertions and deletions.